# How can I apply custom regularization in CNTK (using python)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, backpropagation, cntk, regularized

do you know how can I apply a custom regularization function to CNTK?

In particular, I would like to add to the loss the derivative of the functino wrt to the inputs; something like

```
newLoss = loss + lambda * gradient_F(inputs)
```

where F is the function learned by the model and inputs are the inputs to the model.

How can I achieve this in CNTK? I don't know how to access the gradients wrt to the inputs, and how to take the gradient wrt to the weights of the regularizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, gradient is not a scalar, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to optimize it. The gradient norm might be an interesting thing to add to your loss. To do that, CNTK would have to take the gradient of the gradient norm, which at the time of this writing (July 2017) is not supported. It is however an important feature we want to add in the next few months.

**Update**: One workaround is to do something like this

`noisy_inputs = x + C.random.normal_like(x, scale=0.01)
noisy_model = model.clone('share', {x: noisy_inputs})
auxiliary_loss = C.squared_error(model, noisy_model)`

but you will have to tune the scale of the noise for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes clearly I meant the norm of the gradient (actually the norm to differences of gradients, as outlined in a paper.. but I won't get into it). I was also wondering how to get the gradient of the gradient norm, but since it's not supported I will just wait for now. Thank you again! Are you involved in cntk development?

Comment: Yes I'm involved in CNTK development. One way to approximate what you want is to add small amount of random noise to your data push them through a cloned version of your network and demand small differences between the outputs of the clone and the original one. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

CNTK learners only accept numbers as regularizer (L1/L2) values. If you really want to add your custom regularizer, you can easily implement your own Learner. You will have access to the gradients you need. You will find couple of examples on how to implement your own Learner [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/extend.html#user-defined-learners).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to do this:

```
    def cross_entropy_with_softmax_plus_regularization(model, labels, l2_regularization_weight):
        w_norm = C.Constant(0);
        for p in (model.parameters):
            w_norm = C.plus(w_norm, 0.5*C.reduce_sum(C.square(p)))

        return C.reduce_log_sum_exp(model.output) - 

C.reduce_log_sum_exp(C.times_transpose(labels, model.output)) + l2_regularization_weight*w_norm
```

and my  http://www.telesens.co/2017/09/29/spiral_cntk/  blog post about it

Comment: Hi! I was looking for the norm of the gradient, not the norm of the weight :)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I didn't read the original question properly. You can get access to the gradients by inserting your custom learner function that implements parameter update (see code below). Not sure how those gradients could be accessed from your loss function though..
`
def my_gradient_update(parameters, gradients):
    update_funcs = [];
    for p, g in zip(parameters, gradients):  
        gradient_scale_factor = 0.001
        update_funcs.append(C.assign(p, p - gradient_scale_factor * g))
    return C.combine(update_funcs)
`